# Given the size of $\mathscr{U}, A, B$, how many possible combinations of $A$ and $B$ such that $A\cap B \neq \varnothing$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Given the $\mathscr{U} = n, |A| = c_1$, how many possible set $B$ with size $|B| = c_2$ are there, such that $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Look at the complementary problem: given the $\mathscr{U} = n, |A| = c_1$, how many possible set $B$ with size $|B| = c_2$ are there, such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$.